# XNA: Instancing Cubes, Each Side Different Texture

Tags: xna, textures, hardware, instancing

I am trying to make thousands of instanced cubes, each with a unique texture on each side.

Am I going to have to split each cube into 6 instanced faces, or can I unwrap it in such a way the the texture atlas coordinates will come out right?

My idea is have each cube unwrapped into a 2 tile by 3 tile area as such:

Top     Bottom
Front   Back
Left    Right

Will the unwrap make it into the DrawInstancedPrimitives call?

Next, some cubes will have different textures than others. I was thinking about handling it with an atlas. One 2x3 texture in one slot, and another texture in another, forming a multi-texture image.

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: Do all the cubes have the same 6 textures on their sides? If not, how many combinations are there?

Comment: No many cubes will be the same, but there will be about 60 different combinations. Some only need one square of texture for the whole cube, while others need different textures for each side.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your other question, you're building a Minecraft clone. Now I admit that I'm not sure what Minecraft's renderer does, but I would guess that it's not instancing.

Instancing helps you want to draw many identical *complicated* models in a single batch, with different transforms. While it is possible to use a custom shader to transform the texture coordinates, I don't really think it's a good idea.

If I were going to implement this, I'd probably start with a `DynamicVertexBuffer`. I'd fill the vertex buffer with faces - *not* cubes - doing the world transformation and selection of texture coordinates on the CPU.

**This is basically the same thing that `SpriteBatch` does to draw many different-textured quads** (and, like `SpriteBatch`, you must still use texture atlasing for this to work). But you will have the added advantage of not needing to rebuild the vertex buffer each frame - you only modify it when the world changes.

With this approach you can avoid drawing faces that are between two solid blocks - allowing you to skip most of the geometry. Additionally you can probably treat the vertex buffer as an unordered set of faces - so you'll only have to modify part of it when the world changes.

Comment: Well you would be right about cloning Minecraft. I'm just bored and gave myself a challenge. I too am oblivious to its engine's inner workings other than the fact that each block type extends from a base block, and that each block is part of a chunk and each chunk part of a world. So I came up with this rough code representation: [link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10337688/mcreplicabasedesign.txt)

Comment: Wait... What if I used something like: foreach block, foreach face, if block the face is facing is air, submit face data     This way, blocks with air above only will only submit one face worth of data, but a lone block would submit all 6 faces. the data would consist of transform(based on side submitted) and the texture coord. The batch consists of only one quad then.

Comment: @Nifty255 I'd go with Andrew's suggestion.

Comment: @Nifty255 In case it wasn't clear from my answer: you should be submitting an entire buffer - containing a large number of quads from multiple blocks - as a single batch (a single `GraphicsDevice.Draw*()` call).

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Should this be implemented so?: block has 6 quads, each with transform, tex coord. chunk requests visible sides from each block and gives to world, which gives to game to draw as a single buffer containing all visible faces?

Comment: All I'm really describing is what the buffer should contain once you fill it. How you go about filling it and drawing it is up to you (or worthy of a separate question). It's worth pointing out that the buffer will contain "transformed vertices" as opposed to "vertices and a transform".

Comment: Ah, I see. The vertex declaration, being VertexPositionTexture, will contain all the data for me. Thank you for your help. Now I just need to rewrite my current project which draws each as a cube model. A great many changes coming...

Comment: Would it still be easy-ish on the CPU to split draw calls into chunks? Each chunk would perform its own draw call, so messing with one block doesn't force initialization of a potentially 32k+ size array, but rather an array of only 10k tops. A maximum of 30 draw calls in a single frame. Sound like it would work?

Comment: You get approximately a few hundred draw calls per frame (the "batch limit"). So 30 draw calls per frame is probably fine. But to properly performance tune it, you'll need to take measurements of your running code yourself.